# Area by integration

Tags: calculus, integration, geometry

Find the area of $\int_{0}^{3} xf(x^2)dx$, with $f(x)=\sqrt{-x^2+4x}$

I've integrated this into a pretty gross form, where $A=\frac{1}
{2}sin(2arccos(\frac{1}{2}x^2-1))-arccos(\frac{1}{2}x^2-1)+C{]_0}{_,}{_3}$

Comment: $$f(x) = \sqrt{-x^2+4x}$$ is the equation for the upper half of a circle centered at $(2,0)$ with radius $2$. You could rewrite it as $$f(x) = \sqrt{2^2-(x-2)^2}$$ This means it is only defined over the reals for $0 \le x \le 4$, so $xf(x^2)$ takes complex values for $2 < x \le 3$. Is this intentional?

Comment: I applied u substitution first, and then completed the square to apply trigonometric substitution. I then had to use sin^2(x) identity to reduce the radical. And finally used the double angle identity formula for sin^2(x).

Comment: That is not what I asked. I see what you did. I said that the original problem takes complex values. I asked, is that intentional?

Comment: Not at all………….

Comment: Then I suspect a typo in the original problem. It has no solution over the reals. I'll solve a part of it.

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x) = \sqrt{-x^2+4x} = \sqrt{2^2-(x-2)^2}$$

This is the equation of the upper-half of a circle centered at $(2,0)$ of radius 2.

This means that $f(x)$ takes real values from $x=0$ to $x=4$. So, for $4 < x < 9$, the function is complex. This means, you have:

$$\int_0^3 xf(x^2)dx = \int_0^2 xf(x^2)dx + \int_2^3 xf(x^2)dx$$

The middle one can be simplified using $u=x^2, du=2xdx$, which gives:

$$\int_0^2 xf(x^2)dx = \dfrac{1}{2}\int_0^4 f(u)du$$

But, this integral is just half the area of the upper half of a circle of radius $2$, or a quarter the area of the full circle of radius $2$:

$$\dfrac{1}{4}\pi r^2 = \dfrac{1}{4}\pi(2^2) = \pi$$

This is the real part of the solution. If the original upper bound were $2$, we would stop here and the solution would be $\pi$.

But, the original upper bound was $3$. So, you have:

$$\int_2^3 xf(x^2)dx = \dfrac{1}{2}\int_4^9 f(u)du$$

But, this is a complex-valued function (no real component).